# Force Pi to blackout display at certain times

Tags: pi-3, display, shutdown

I'm using a Pi 3 to display content in Kiosk mode (Chromium). I've disabled the PIXEL screensaver to prevent screen blackouts during operational hours.

What I need is the display to blackout during certain times (off-hours, example: 5.30pm - 8.00am) to reduce LCD burnout.

Is there a config option or third-party tool that can help me attain this? I don't need display timeout due to inactivity - but time-based control over the display.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample `cron` script. It will turn the display off at 22h00, and put the display on at 6h00.

```
0 22 * * * /usr/bin/xset -display :0 dpms force off
0 06 * * * /usr/bin/xset -display :0 dpms force on
```

This script should be run by the same user running the X server, probably `pi` on a raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tvservice command in a script or crontab to blackout the screen